# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a$ and $b$ have different signs, and $|a|\ge |b|$, show $|a+b|\le |a|$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Does anyone know of a way to argue this with more brevity?

I have an argument but I think it too verbose.

I would be really surprised if there is not a significantly more efficient argument one could make. But I have not been able to construct one for the life me.

Context: I was reading page 93 in Foundations of Modern Analysis by Avner Friedman and he mentioned this result in passing. I wanted to verify it for myself, thinking it would be trivial, but apparently no (not for me at least).

---

*My attempt:*

If $|a| \ge |b|$, then $-|a| \le b \le |a|$.

Consider two cases: (1) $a \geq 0 \geq b $ and (2) $a \leq 0 \leq b$.

**Case (1):**

We can state $2a \geq a \geq a+b$. We have $|a| = a$ since $a\geq 0$.

So we get $|a| \geq a+b$.

And secondly we can state $a+b\geq b \geq 2b$. We have $b \geq -|a|$.

We get $a+b\geq -|a|$.

Hence the two together: $-|a| \leq a+b \leq |a| \iff |a+b|\leq |a|$.

**Case (2):**

We can state $2a \leq a \leq a+b$. And $a \leq 0$ means $|a| = -a$.
Whence $-|a| \leq a+b$.

Moreover, $a+b\leq b \leq 2b$, together with $b \leq |a|$, gives us $a+b \leq |a|$.

Again we get $-|a| \leq a+b \leq |a|$. $\blacksquare$

---

This must be able to be shortened, no?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show $|a+b|\leq |a|$, it's enough to show $(a+b)^2\leq a^2$, which is true because:
$$
(a+b)^2-a^2=b^2+2ab=|b||b|-2|a||b|=|b|\underbrace{(|b|-|a|)}_{\leq 0}-|a||b|\leq 0.
$$

Comment: If brevity is the main criterion, I don't think you need the $-|a||b|$ term at the end, since surely $2|a|>|a|>|b|$.

Comment: Gosh, why did it not occur to me to consider the square. Beautiful solution, exactly in line with what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$a,b$ have different sign means $a\cdot b<0$, So we have $~ a\cdot (-b)>0$, which means

$a$ and $-b$ have the same sign, so $|a-(-b)|$ equals the bigger modulus (which is $|a|$) minus the smaller modulus (which is $|b|$)

$$|a+b|=|a-(-b)|=|a|-|(-b)|\le|a|$$

Comment: How do you justify the second equality?

Comment: $a$ and $-b$ have the same sign, so the $|a-(-b)|$ equals the bigger one $|a|$ minus the smaller one $|-b|$. @TedShifrin

Comment: Maybe it would be better to write some English sentences and not just write symbols. And your very first line is mispunctuated and confusing ... Extra comma? Since $p\implies q$, then what? Again, too many symbols and not enough explanation.

Comment: OK, I add some words to explain it and hope this will be more clear @TedShifrin